# Azure VHD Access Security

Tags: security, azure, virtual-machine

Who can access the data stored on a Azure VM and attached disks?  For example, if I create a SQL Server VM from the gallery and attach a 1TB disk (E:) can an employee of Microsoft access and read data from the VM or disk?

Comment: This isn't a programming question and doesn't fit on StackOverflow. Not sure if it's in the Azure terms & conditions, but that might be a good place to start.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have some questions about the privacy of your data. Perhaps the official statement is useful: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/trust-center/privacy/